# Chrome application to a local file is loaded with an empty profile

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell

I want to load a local HTML file as an application ('shortcut'). So I created an application from a website (Settings -> More tools -> Create shortcut...) and then edited the .desktop file to use the --app switch instead of --app-id and to use --user-data-dir instead of --profile-directory, to point to the Default profile. I also tried combinations of the original and new switches. I also used the --class switch so it shows as a separate application on the desktop (the value is copied from the value Chrome assigned to tartupWMClass).

Using Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 20.04

In all of these attempts, when Chrome starts, it loads under a random profile (so no extensions)

The line I edited is:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/ittay/.config/google-chrome/Default  --app=file:///home/ittay/vGrive/local.html --class=crx_ihcebalajepmfcapbokdedngneimhbdp
```

Comment: You tagged with unity. Are you using the Unity desktop?

Comment: Please also specify Ubuntu version. Precise information on the desktop you use is relevant to this problem.